# Regexp.Short representation of ip address

Tags: c#, regex, foreach

I need in short representation of ip address.Instead 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 should be 0.0.0.0/0 For example,

**the source file:**

```
set address "UntrustGn" "172.30.2.130/32" 172.30.2.130 255.255.255.255
set address "UntrustGn" "190.8.35.230/32" 190.8.35.230 255.255.255.255
set address "UntrustGn" "217.118.69.0/24" 217.118.69.0 255.255.255.0
```

**output file:**

```
set address "UntrustGn" "172.30.2.130/32" 172.30.2.13/32
set address "UntrustGn" "190.8.35.230/32" 190.8.35.230/32
set address "UntrustGn" "217.118.69.0/24" 217.118.69.0/24
```

something I have tried to do. But did not achieve the desired result....
help!please!

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
    string patternZone = @"set address "".*"" "".*"" [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)";

    var matchesZone = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), patternZone);

    foreach(var match in matchesZone)
     {
        txt.AppendText(match.ToString().Replace(" 255.255.255.255", "/32");
     }
```

Comment: So you don't know how to calculate network mask or what?

Comment: I need programmatically find substring of the form (here mask of ip address) and convert it to short form (via /). 255.255.255.0 should be /24

Comment: so what **exactly** you cannot do?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"""(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(/\d+)""\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}

public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    // You can vary the replacement text for each match on-the-fly
    return "\"$1$2\" $3$2";
}
```